# Rundeck on kubernetes can't do https

Tags: kubernetes, rundeck

It seems my rundeck can't do https. I'm doing a ssl offload at a loadbalancer. The following is a snippet of my deployment yml

```
 containers:
    - name: rundeck
      image:rundeck/rundeck:3.1.1
      env:
        - name: RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL
          value: "https://rundeck.somehost.io"
        - name: SERVER_SECURED_URL
          value: "https://rundeck.somehost.io"
        - name: RUNDECK_JVM_SETTINGS
          value: "-Dserver.web.context=/rundeck -Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true"
```

I've follow most tips form the net but my rundeck still looking for http after login

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the ssl settings, for example:

```
    args: ["-Dserver.https.port=4443 -Drundeck.ssl.config=/home/rundeck/server/config/ssl.properties"]
```

But you will need to add a certificate (for example a self-certificate) to the container.

You can try:

1) extend the Rundeck official image (like [this](https://github.com/ltamaster/rundeck-docker-ssl-example/tree/master/rundeck) )

2) create a volume with the certificate and mount it on /home/rundeck/etc/truststore (also you might need to mount the /home/rundeck/server/config/ssl.properties with the right password ). BTW, I haven't tried that

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `-Drundeck.ssl.config` parameter and SSL port (`-Dserver.https.port=4443`) [too](https://github.com/ltamaster/rundeck-docker-ssl-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml) in your Rundeck section (the example has HAproxy and MySQL as part of the container but you can use the Rundeck section).

This parameter point to a file with this content (with your paths and certificate, you've full SSL configuration explanation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/ssl.html))

```
keystore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/keystore
keystore.password=password
key.password=password
truststore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore
truststore.password=password
```

You can check the entire example project [here](https://github.com/ltamaster/rundeck-docker-ssl-example).

Alternatively, you can use this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jordan/rundeck/) maybe easiest to configure (check the "SSL" parameters).

Comment: But I don't have a ssl on my rundeck pod. The ssl is terminated at my load balancer